# Quelle est l’origine de l’expression «avoir à voir»?

Tags: étymologie, expressions-idiomatiques

[***Avoir à voir***](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_%C3%A0_voir) signifie *avoir un rapport*. Par exemple:

> Sa maladie n’a rien à voir avec la chaleur.

Mais il n’est pas évident quelle est la signification de *voir* dans cette expression. Alors, comment a *avoir à voir* pris sa signification?

Il y a des questions sûr les expressions equivalentes [en portugais au SE.Portuguese Language](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/851/tem-a-ver-qual-%C3%A9-a-origem-desta-express%C3%A3o)  (en portugaise et anglais), et [en espagnol au SE.Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15282/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-del-modismo-tener-que-ver-con). La version portugaise est la plus anciène, mais a seulement des réponses spéculatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premièrement, « *avoir à voir avec* » est classé ainsi à l'entrée *voir* du *TLFi* :

> **1<sup>re</sup> Section.** Domaine des *perceptions phys.*; *p. ext.*, domaine des *perceptions phys.* mettant en jeu un sens
>   différent de celui de la vue.
>  [...]
>   **2<sup>e</sup> Section.** Domaine de la *pensée*. Percevoir par l'esprit, se représenter en esprit.
>
> - I. − **Voir** + compl.
> - II. − Empl. trans. indir. **Voir à**
> - III. − Empl. **abstraits**.
>
>   - A. −
>
>     - 1. Voir +(loc.) adv. Avoir une certaine conception des choses; se faire une certaine idée d'elles.
>     - 2. Façon, manière de voir. Opinion, conception.
>   - B. − Synon. de *comprendre*.
>   - **C.** − P. ext. [Exprime une relation, un rapport; constr. le plus souvent avec ne... rien]
>
>     - − **Avoir à voir avec...**
>
>       - ♦ [Le suj. et le compl. désignent des pers.] Avoir un lien; avoir quelque chose de commun avec.
>       - ♦ [Le suj. et le compl. désignent des choses] Être du même ordre que; aller dans le même sens que.
>       - ♦ [Le suj. est un pron. neutre] Cela n'a rien à voir avec nous. Cela ne nous concerne pas.
>     - − **Avoir à voir dans...**
>
>       - ♦ [Le suj. désigne une pers.]
>
>         - Être concerné par.
>         - Avoir à redire à.
>       - ♦ [Le suj. désigne une chose] Être en cause.
>
> [...]
>   [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* - TLFi, extraits de la structure de l'entrée [*voir*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voir) ]

On note par exemple qu'« *avoir à voir dans* » peut vouloir dire « *avoir à [redire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/redire) à* », qui lui n'implique pas de dire à nouveau mais plutôt de *critiquer*. Nous sommes loin du domaine des perceptions physiques. Il s'agit plutôt d'extensions des sens abstraits comme *juger*, *considérer*, *deviner*, *connaître*, *s'occuper* et *veiller* (sur) que *voir* peut signifier. <sup>1</sup>

---

Plus spécifiquement, au *Dictionnaire étymologique et historique du galloroman (Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch - FEW)*, à l'entrée [*voir*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/269544) (voir p. 421, 2e colonne), ce qui précède « *n'avoir rien à voir* », c'est la tournure :

> *n'avoir que voir à* qch « n'avoir pas à s'occuper de » OudC, 1640
>
> [ Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch - FEW, *vidēre* ]

[image]
<sup>La référence au *FEW*, [*Curiosités françoises*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pDkMIjV13VEC&dq=oudin%20curiosit%C3%A9s&pg=PA578#v=snippet&q=%22que%20voir%22&f=false) (1640) de A. Oudin.</sup>

C'est complètement sorti d'usage (mais sa *forme* me rappelle celle de *n'avoir que faire de*). C'est une **réduction** de la valeur abstraite quand elle est ramenée à un sujet nom de chose qui la fait glisser vers la *mise en rapport/se rapporter à* (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, dir. A. Rey, ed. *Le Robert*, à *voir*). Puis, de *n'avoir rien à voir à* à *n'avoir rien à voir dans/avec* ; le *FEW* note attesté en 1718 et 1773, alors que le *DHLF* note uniquement 1718 pour la forme avec *avec*.

---

En résumé il s'agit, par extension, d'une réduction des sens abstraits de *voir*, d'après la tournure « *n'avoir que voir à* [quelque chose] ».

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> C'est n'est pas le sujet ici et je ne parle pas portugais, mais j'ai cru comprendre qu'il y avait aussi une grande variété de sens avec [*ver*](http://www.ultralingua.com/onlinedictionary/dictionary#src_lang=Portuguese&dest_lang=French&query=ver) ([2](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/ingles/index.php?lingua=portugues-ingles&palavra=ver)), mais peut-être que les sens abstraits dont je traite sont davantage réalisés ou plus usuels avec *considerar* ??</sub>

Comment: Merci bien. L'expression *n'avoir que voir à [quelque chose]* est bien claire, même si on prend *voir* au sens physique, quand il s'agit d'une personne. Oui, en portugais, *ver* a essentiellement les mêmes sens que *voir* en français. C’est plutôt la préposition *com* (*avec*) qui est difficile à comprendre.

Comment: @Jacinto Je vous en prie. Votre question ne m'a pas permis de comprendre que c'était la préposition qui posait problème... La préposition _avec_ sert à relier cette chose à laquelle on _voit_ dans les sens abstraits, si j'ai bien compris. Merci ! p.s. j'ai passé un bon moment à passer votre Q&A dans _Google_ translate en français, puis en anglais, etc. mais la traduction n'est pas très précise, selon le style etc. peut-être lors d'une prochaine question résumer en quelques lignes le contenu des réponses ? Merci !

Comment: Je croix que ma difficulté a été que j’ai compris *X a qqc à voir* comme *X a qqc pour X voir* et non comme *X a qqc pour être vu*.

Comment: @Jacinto Considérez ceci : _les symptômes de sa maladie ne sont pas du tout du même ordre que ceux associés à la chaleur_. Dans cette tournure, c'est le _que_ qui tisse le lien entre les deux éléments qu'on compare par la négative. Les prépositions c'est souvent mystérieux pour moi aussi. Merci !

Comment: J'ai traduit la question e la longue response portugaise en anglais.